# Why doesn't `\addtocounter` work inside an \edef?

Tags: counters

When running the following code the counter `testcount` will update outside but not inside the `\edef`. Why?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\global\newcounter{testcount}
\message{TESTCOUNT NEW: \thetestcount}
% outputs 0

\setcounter{testcount}{1}
\message{TESTCOUNT SET: \thetestcount}
% outputs 1

\addtocounter{testcount}{3}
\message{TESTCOUNT ADD: \thetestcount}
% outputs 4

\edef\trytoadd{%
    \addtocounter{testcount}{3}
    \message{TESTCOUNT EDEF: \thetestcount}
    % still outputs 4 - why?
}
\trytoadd


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\edef` only performs macro expansion, not assignments.

Comment: It's actually a bit surprising that `\addtocounter` inside `\edef` doesn't break, but in the linked question you see why this happens: essentially by luck.

Comment: also you can not use `\global` with `\newcounter` (it doesn't error but it doesn't do anything useful)